# React Select Async places the cursor(caret) at the start of the placeholder when input is focused

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using React Async Select and I found out that by default it places the cursor(caret) at the start of the placeholder when the input is focused. How can I place the cursor at the end? I did not find any prop that I can pass to select component to achieve that behavior. Here's my AsyncSelect:

```
          <AsyncSelect
            styles={selectStyle}
            openDropdown={openDropdown}
            setOpenDropdown={setOpenDropdown}
            emoji={emoji}
            loadOptions={suggestions}
            placeholder="City, Place, Art, Architecture, Park, Collection..."
            onChange={handleSearch}
            components  ={{ Control }}
          />
```